# how to write json objects one by one in to a json object in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need to create an answer JSON with nested objects

I tried to use mappable but it won't solve the problem

I need to create this kind of array

```
{  
   "interactionId":"daade6b6adcd8b063a355e28bc1f1341",
   "futureSurveyAnswers":[  
      {  
         "type":"imagepicker",
         "qcode":"vxo20zeezo",
         "values":[  
            {  
               "value":"lion"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "type":"radiogroup",
         "qcode":"s4ep4s0shf",
         "values":[  
            {  
               "value":"item1"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "type":"checkbox",
         "qcode":"76k5cpnpki",
         "values":[  
            {  
               "value":"item1"
            },
            {  
               "value":"item2"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "originalResultArray":"{\"question2\":\"item1\",\"question3\":[\"item1\",\"item2\"],\"question1\":\"lion\"}"
}
```

Comment: Show what you tried yet.

Answer (score 2):

Currently probably the best solution to use is `Codable` protocol. There are many examples and tutorials online so please do check one or two, I am sure you will find it very simple to use.

The point is that you can encode concrete classes or structures directly to (and from) JSON. So your problem is then not in JSON itself but just structuring your classes. For instance:

```
class Survey {

    class Answer {
        enum AnswerType: String {
            case imagepicker
        }
        class Value {
            var value: String?
        }

        var type: AnswerType = .imagepicker
        var qcode: String?
        var values: [Value] = [Value]()
    }

    let interactionId: String
    var futureSurveyAnswers: [Answer] = [Answer]()
    var originalResultArray: String?

    init(interactionId: String) { self.interactionId = interactionId }
}
```

This way you can easily modify your structure as you want to. For instance:

```
let survey = Survey(interactionId: "0")
survey.futureSurveyAnswers.append({
    let answer = Survey.Answer()
    answer.qcode = "test"
    return answer
}())
```

So to extend it to codable all you need to do is actually append `Codable` protocol to your class and any embedded component:

```
class Survey: Codable {

    class Answer: Codable {
        enum AnswerType: String, Codable {
            case imagepicker
        }
        class Value: Codable {
            var value: String?
        }

        var type: AnswerType = .imagepicker
        var qcode: String?
        var values: [Value] = [Value]()
    }

    let interactionId: String
    var futureSurveyAnswers: [Answer] = [Answer]()
    var originalResultArray: String?

    init(interactionId: String) { self.interactionId = interactionId }
}
```

Now you can get JSON as simple as the following:

```
let survey = Survey(interactionId: "0")
survey.futureSurveyAnswers.append({
    let answer = Survey.Answer()
    answer.values.append({
        let value = Survey.Answer.Value()
        value.value = "some"
        return value
    }())
    answer.qcode = "test"
    return answer
}())

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
if let jsonData = try? encoder.encode(survey) {
    print("Generated data: \(jsonData)")
}
```

I hope this puts you in the right direction.

From comments this is what I used as a test example for JSON:

```
class Survey: Codable {

    class Answer: Codable {
        enum AnswerType: String, Codable {
            case imagepicker
        }
        class Value: Codable {
            var value: String?
            init(value: String? = nil) { self.value = value }
        }

        var type: AnswerType = .imagepicker
        var qcode: String?
        var values: [Value] = [Value]()
    }

    let interactionId: String
    var futureSurveyAnswers: [Answer] = [Answer]()
    var originalResultArray: String?

    init(interactionId: String) { self.interactionId = interactionId }
}

func addTestAnswer(to survey: Survey) {
    let answer = Survey.Answer()
    answer.values.append(.init(value: "Random value \(Int.random(in: 1...100))"))
    answer.values.append(.init(value: "Random value \(Int.random(in: 1...100))"))
    answer.values.append(.init(value: "Random value \(Int.random(in: 1...100))"))
    answer.values.append(.init(value: "Random value \(Int.random(in: 1...100))"))
    survey.futureSurveyAnswers.append(answer)
}

func testRandomSurveyJSON() {
    let survey = Survey(interactionId: "randomSurvey")
    addTestAnswer(to: survey)
    addTestAnswer(to: survey)
    addTestAnswer(to: survey)
    addTestAnswer(to: survey)
    addTestAnswer(to: survey)

    print("Got JSON: \(String(data: try! JSONEncoder().encode(survey), encoding: .utf8)!)")
}
```

And got the following result:

```
Got JSON: {"interactionId":"randomSurvey","futureSurveyAnswers":[{"type":"imagepicker","values":[{"value":"Random value 74"},{"value":"Random value 4"},{"value":"Random value 26"},{"value":"Random value 93"}]},{"type":"imagepicker","values":[{"value":"Random value 43"},{"value":"Random value 65"},{"value":"Random value 38"},{"value":"Random value 88"}]},{"type":"imagepicker","values":[{"value":"Random value 56"},{"value":"Random value 88"},{"value":"Random value 57"},{"value":"Random value 94"}]},{"type":"imagepicker","values":[{"value":"Random value 66"},{"value":"Random value 52"},{"value":"Random value 89"},{"value":"Random value 27"}]},{"type":"imagepicker","values":[{"value":"Random value 53"},{"value":"Random value 93"},{"value":"Random value 30"},{"value":"Random value 55"}]}]}
```

which seems to be correct.

Comment: how to add data to the values section

Comment: @VSoftwareSolutions Do you mean like: `answer.values.append({
            let value = Survey.Answer.Value()
            value.value = "some"
            return value
        }())`

Comment: how can i print out the whole data set once i write all data

Comment: @VSoftwareSolutions Not sure what you mean; the JSON? JSON is binary data but is partially human readable when converted to UTF8 string. To do so all you need to do is initialize a `String` with JSON data using UTF8 string encoding: `print("\(String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!)")`

Comment: im writing data one at a time to this object so once its compleate, is there a way to print the whole json object

Comment: @VSoftwareSolutions Yes, you can print it the way I posted in my previous comment. So at any given time you can just convert it to JSON data and print that data by converting it to UTF8 string. You should even be able to print it in console when on breakpoint by using `po` command. Simply enter this line: `po String(data: (try! JSONEncoder().encode(survey)), encoding: .utf8)!` in debugger console.

Comment: but it gives me this error "Argument type 'Survey.Type' does not conform to expected type 'Encodable'"

Comment: and when i do it as you said in previous comment it gives me an empty object . data in survey :: {
    futureSurveyAnswers =     (
    );
    interactionId = "";
}

Comment: im building a survey questions... so the post request body is dynamic depends on the number of questions. and im loading the questions one by one.. and i need to append data to this object one question at a time and finally when all questions are answerd i send the post request. so in the end i need to print out the whole answer object to make sure its correct.. can you help me

Comment: @VSoftwareSolutions It is hard to say what went wrong without seeing your code. Maybe you should post another question about it. Or my check the update as I added a full working example with printing a JSON. Check what is the difference from your code and try to find a fix for your case.